# Async in Custom pipe Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm currently working on an angular custom translation pipe which need a lot of async.

Here is my current code

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'translatorPipe'
})
export class TranslatorPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private languageService: LanguageService) {}

  transform(input: string, ...args: unknown[]): Observable<Observable<string>> {
    let languageObservable = this.languageService.selectedLanguageObservable.pipe(map((response) => {
      let translationObservable = this.languageService.translateContent([input], response).pipe(map((translations) => {
        return this.languageService.getBestTranslationText(translations[0]);
      }));
      return translationObservable;
    }));
    return languageObservable;
  }
}
```

Problem is : to use this pipe, I have to combine it with a double async pipe  like follows :

```html
{{ post.title | translatorPipe | async | async }}
```

Which is not really good practice or understandable code.

My question is : How can I make my pipe self sufficient so that I don't have to combine it with the async pipe?

Thanks by advance for your ideas

Comment: Regarding design consideration, why don't you fetch all the translations from the API and use your pipe to search through the local list of key-value pairs? This way you would save multiple API calls if you have a lot of values to translate on a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's indeed a bit too convoluted to me understandable. Perhaps it's best to just extend the `async` pipe and restructure your observable logic:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'translator',
  pure: false,
})
export class TranslatorPipe extends AsyncPipe implements PipeTransform {
  private input$ = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
  
  private language$ = this.ls.selectedLanguageObservable.pipe(
    switchMap((selectedLanguage) => this.input$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((input) => this.ls.translateContent([input], selectedLanguage))
    )),
    map(([translations]) => this.ls.getBestTranslationText(translations)),
    shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })
  );
  
  constructor(private ls: LanguageService, cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    super(cd);
  }

  transform<T>(obj: Observable<T> | Subscribable<T> | Promise<T> | string): T | null;
  transform<T>(input: string): T | null {
    this.input$.next(input);
    
    return super.transform(this.language$);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
{{ post.title | translator }}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. I got two problems with this code :
- First : it returns null for everycase
- Second : the pure false, makes that the pipe is called again and again, and this pipe is making an api request that must be called the less time possible.

Comment: @BenoitBonavia I've updated my answer. I don't know why it would return null for every case. Can you add the `LanguageServce` implementation to your question? Secondly, I've made it now so that the observable itself doesn't change anymore, so it should only call the API once when necessary. The `pure: false` is necessary, because it extends the `async` pipe which is also not pure

Comment: Thank you so much ! With the update, everything is working well !